# Split dataframe column containing iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with one of the columns containing some sequential data in a form of list or tuple (always the same length), my aim is to split this column into several new columns, ideally updating one of the existing columns.

Here is the minimal example

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

data = DataFrame({"label": [a for a in "abcde"], "x": range(5)})
print(data)

  label  x
0     a  0
1     b  1
2     c  2
3     d  3
4     e  4
```

The fictional way, using nonexisting function *splittuple* would be something like this

```
data[["x", "x2"]] = data["x"].apply(lambda x: (x, x*2)).splittuple(expand = True)
```

resulting in

```
  label  x  x2
0     a  0  0
1     b  1  2
2     c  2  4
3     d  3  6
4     e  4  8
```

Of course I can do it like this, though the solution is bit cloggy

```
newdata = DataFrame(data["x"].apply(lambda x: (x, x*2)).tolist(), columns = ["x", "x2"])
data.drop("x", axis = 1, inplace = True)
data = concat((data, newdata), axis = 1)
print(data)

  label  x  x2
0     a  0   0
1     b  1   2
2     c  2   4
3     d  3   6
4     e  4   8
```

Alternative even more ugly solution

```
data[["x", "x2"]] = 
  data["x"].apply(lambda x: "{} {}".format(x, x*2)).str.split(expand = True).astype(int)
```

Could you suggest more elegant way to do this type of transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not so fast with `apply` and `Series`:

```
tup = data["x"].apply(lambda x: (x, x*2))
data[["x", "x2"]] = tup.apply(pd.Series)

print (data)
  label  x  x2
0     a  0   0
1     b  1   2
2     c  2   4
3     d  3   6
4     e  4   8
```

Faster is use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
tup = data["x"].apply(lambda x: (x, x*2))
data[["x", "x2"]] = pd.DataFrame(tup.values.tolist())
print (data)
  label  x  x2
0     a  0   0
1     b  1   2
2     c  2   4
3     d  3   6
4     e  4   8
```

**Timings**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"label": [a for a in "abcde"], "x": range(5)})
data = pd.concat([data]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
tup = data["x"].apply(lambda x: (x, x*2))


data[["x", "x2"]] = tup.apply(pd.Series)
data[["y", "y2"]] = pd.DataFrame(tup.values.tolist())
print (data)

In [266]: %timeit data[["x", "x2"]] = tup.apply(pd.Series)
1 loop, best of 3: 836 ms per loop

In [267]: %timeit data[["y", "y2"]] = pd.DataFrame(tup.values.tolist())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: hi @jezrael , can you pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335265/how-to-perform-drop-duplicates-with-multiple-condition-in-a-pandas-dataframe