# how to perform drop_duplicates with multiple condition in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I have a df,

```
    Sr.No   Name    Class   Data
0   1       Sri     1       sri is a good player
1   ''      Sri     2       sri is good in cricket
2   ''      Sri     3       sri went out
3   2       Ram     1       Ram is a good player
4   ''      Ram     2       sri is good in cricket
5   ''      Ram     3       Ram went out
6   3       Sri     1       sri is a good player
7   ''      Sri     2       sri is good in cricket
8   ''      Sri     3       sri went out
9   4       Sri     1       sri is a good player
10  ''      Sri     2       sri is good in cricket
11  ''      Sri     3       sri went out
12  ''      Sri     4       sri came back
```

I am trying to drop duplicates based on ["Name","Class","Data"]. The goal is to drop duplicates based on all sentences per Sr No.

My expected output is,

```
out_df


    Sr.No   Name    Class   Data
0   1       Sri     1       sri is a good player
1           Sri     2       sri is good in cricket
2           Sri     3       sri went out
3   2       Ram     1       Ram is a good player
4           Ram     2       sri is good in cricket
5           Ram     3       Ram went out
9   4       Sri     1       sri is a good player
10          Sri     2       sri is good in cricket
11          Sri     3       sri went out
12          Sri     4       sri came back
```

Comment: Can you please print `df.to_dict()` and paste the output in your question? Your dataframes are so difficult to copy.

Comment: Your to_dict output is different from what your posted dataframe is. Please do make it consistent so your expected output is clear ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , I edited my question with the proper `df.to_dict()` pls check

Comment: I dont get you, when I do `pd.DataFrame(my_dict)` it gives my actual df properly.

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood the question initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dummy column with a `groupby` + `transform` operation.

```
v = df.groupby(df['Class'].diff().le(0).cumsum())['Data'].transform(' '.join)
```

Or,

```
v = df['Data'].groupby(df['Class'].diff().le(0).cumsum()).transform(' '.join)
```

This dummy column becomes a factor when deciding what rows are to be dropped.

```
m = df.assign(Foo=v).duplicated(["Name", "Class", "Data", "Foo"])    
df[~m]

    Class                    Data Name Sr.No
0       1   sri is  a good player  Sri     1
1       2  sri is good in cricket  Sri      
2       3            sri went out  Sri      
3       1    Ram is a good player  Ram     2
4       2  sri is good in cricket  Ram      
5       3            Ram went out  Ram      
9       1   sri is  a good player  Sri     4
10      2  sri is good in cricket  Sri      
11      3            sri went out  Sri      
12      4           sri came back  Sri
```

---

**Details**

Form groups from the monotonically increasing `Class` values -

```
i = df['Class'].diff().le(0).cumsum()
i

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
Name: Class, dtype: int64
```

Use this to group, and transform `Data` with a `str.join` operation -

```
v = df.groupby(i)['Data'].transform(' '.join)
```

Which is simply a column of joined strings. Finally, assign the dummy column and call `duplicated` -

```
m = df.assign(Foo=v).duplicated(["Name", "Class", "Data", "Foo"]) 
m

0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: works very well, thank you coldspped and @jezrael . coldspeed may I know how many years you've been in data science/pandas ?

Comment: @pyd You're welcome. As for your question, I've been working with pandas for around 5 and a half months.

Comment: what is "Data" in this line `df.groupby(df.Class.diff().le(0).cumsum()).Data.transform(' '.join)` my column or a keyword. ]

Comment: @pyd A column. I've edited for clarity. Also, you unmarked. Did it not work?

Comment: not like that, @coldspeed , I was expecting for some more answers from ppl .I will approve your answer . you're very helpful.  cant we pass df["Data"] in the same place

Comment: I understood its a column but the column will be dynamic and I cannot pass df["Data"] why ?

Comment: @pyd Where do you want to pass it to?

Comment: I want to pass `df.groupby(df.Class.diff().le(0).cumsum()).df["Data"].transform(' '.join)` instead `df.groupby(df.Class.diff().le(0).cumsum()).Data.transform(' '.join)` because my columns value will be changed for each case so we should hardcode the column name

Comment: @pyd But with `df["Data"]` you're still hardcoding the column name?

Comment: actually for each case, column names will be different, so we cannot hardcode,

Comment: @pyd Unless I'm missing something, you can also do this with: `df['Data'].groupby(df['Class'].diff().le(0).cumsum()).transform(' '.join)`

Comment: ya, when we are having df["col_name"] we can pass dynamic values but when df.col_name, we cannot pass dynamic values

Comment: @pyd I know that. If you see my edit, the one in my answer _also_ works.

Comment: could you pls update the solution with `df['Data'].groupby(df['Class'].diff().le(0).cumsum()).transf‌​orm(' '.join)`

Comment: @coldspeed, what if the class column has `column 1, column2, ..` instead `1,2,3,...` I am getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @pyd Then you'd need something like `df['Class'].eq('column 1').cumsum()`? If that doesn't work, would recommend you opening a new question.

Comment: do we need to mention the value of the first cell under column "class" ?

Comment: @pyd Yes, the first value in the sequence.